# Polymer "firebase-document" returns value as Object to do dom-repeat how can i convert it as array?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymerfire

[image: SHAPSHOT OF DATA]

Just like doing `shapshot.val()` is there any attribute to achieve this ?

Comment: I think this topic headline would be more clear "How to convert an object, returned from Polymer's firebase-document, into array?"

Comment: I'd just like to add that there is the element firebase-query wich specialize at bringing data as an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just convert those number keys into array, you can simply do:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i in obj) {
    arr.push(obj[i]);
}
```

where `obj` is object returned from `firebase-document` and `arr` is the result